# mysql window function working on production server, not on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mariadb, raspberry-pi3

I have just setup my Raspberry Pi (RPI) with OSMC (debian 9 stretch), nginx, PHP 7, Mysql  and phpmyadmin

All seems to be working except the mysql windows functions. For example the following query produces a syntax error:

```
SELECT sum(propertyId) over() FROM `properties`;
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '() FROM `properties` LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

However, the exact same query and database tables works fine on my production server.

Here are the setups (from the respective phpmyadmins) for the two servers:

RASPBERRY PI (not working)

```
Database server
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 - Debian 9.1
Protocol version: 10
User: phpmyadmin@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Web server
nginx/1.10.3
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.0.30-0+deb9u1
```

PRODUCTION SERVER (WORKING FINE)

```
Database server
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.2.12-MariaDB-log - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10
User: montegoventures@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Web server
cpsrvd 11.70.0.53
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 5.6.30
```

I have tried countless times to upgrade the mariadb on the RPI to version 10.2 but no matter what I do, it still installs version 10.1.26

So, any suggestions on how I can get my simple query to work on my RPI server? Yes, I know it is a trivial query, but if I can't get that simple one to work on the RPI, how can I get my complex queries to work?

thanks

Comment: You're using MariaDB. Window functions were first introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0. See [Window Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/). You need to update MariaDB in your RPI, see [MariaDB Downloads](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.2.17/).

Comment: that is what I figured. Problem is, I cannot seem to update - I have loaded up the repository for 10.2, removed 10.1, but when I got to install, it still installs 10.1. Any ideas on that?

Comment: See [Install MariaDB 10.2 on Raspbian Stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77646/install-mariadb-10-2-on-raspbian-stretch). Try a search like "Compilation and installation of MariaDB in Raspberry PI" in your preferred search engine.

Comment: Avoid using Windowing functions.  If you need help, describe what the query is supposed to do, perhaps we can translate for you.  Smells like some kind of simple `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @RickJames I like windows functions. They are quite useful in some cases. Well, unless they are misused.